# error does not appear on the register page

Tags: javascript, cross-origin-read-blocking

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/users. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

```
const Register = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [confPassword, setConfPassword] = useState('');
    const [msg, setMsg] = useState('');
    const history = useHistory();

    const Register = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try{
            await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/users',{
                name: name,
                email: email,
                password: password,
                confPassword: confPassword
            });
            history.push("/");
        }catch(error){
            if (error.response) {
                setMsg(error.response.data.msg);
            }

        }
    }
```

I tried to enter the wrong password so that an error message appears on the register page, I want the error to appear on the register page

Comment: CORS is an server side control. It appears that your server is currently running on localhost:5000, what is your client running on? The actual React code appears fine, but you'll need to post more information on how you currently have things configured.

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of CORS errors and actually i fixed them by below solutions :

- Using a CORS [extension](https://mybrowseraddon.com/access-control-allow-origin.html).
- Passing correct headers and data to the API.
- Disable CORS in backend.